# How do AGAL registers get added or subtracted when they 'contain' 3D vectors?

Tags: actionscript-3, fragment-shader, stage3d, agal

I'm working on adding a shadow to planetary rings in a space game I'm developing. For this I need to calculate where a cylinder (the shadow of the planet) intersects with a plane (the mesh of the rings).

I'm being impeded by not being able to see how the 'sub' and 'add' opcodes deal with each component of a register. On this page http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/what-is-agal.html there is a graphic that illustrates what each of the opcodes does; It describes the addition and subtraction (amongst other calculations) as 'component-wise'.

Does this mean, if I'm adding or subtracting 3D vectors, the x, y, z (and w?) components will be affected independently of one another? And, if so, how do the registers 'know' NOT to do that if adding or subtracting, say, 2 Numbers? Do I need to deal with each component separately for 3D vectors or would just using 'add' or 'sub' add or subtract the 2 vectors correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Component-wise means that each vector component will be added/substracted/etc separatelly from each other. For example, adding two vectors together:

   (x1, y1, z1, w1) + (x2, y2, z2, w2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2, w1 + w2)
2. You use vector swizzling if you need to add only some components in arbitrary order:

   v1.xzy + v2.wwx = (v1.x + v2.w, v1.z + v2.w, v1.y + v2.x)

Comment: This sounds sensible. To answer the 'second part' of my question; How does addition work, then, when dealing with a Number value. Is it able to work the same way as you describe because only the least significant component (z?) of the register is required to hold the value? For a Number value would the x and y components generally remain at 0?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't have my Stage3D code in front of me, sorry, but from memory it's just occurred to me that, when I need to pass a Number to the fragment shader (let's say to describe how 'much' specular should be included on a surface), I've been passing the value in via setProgramConstantsFromVector and setting each component to the same value, so my additional question about the shader only needing to use the z component for Numbers may have been ill-thought-out. That said, I HAVE noticed that, when using the 'slt' or 'sge' opcodes, it's only the z component that holds the on/off flag of 0 or 1.

Comment: You can't pass only one Number, you have to pass at least four. Every entry in constants array becomes a constant component, like `Vector<Number>([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])` becomes in `shader vc.xyzw = (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0)`.